# Український фразеологізм у значенні не було варто витрачених зусиль

Tags: фразеологізми

Позавчора казав: "**Ми рік працювали заради 30 калік/інвалідів**". Звучить як калька російськомовного фразеологізму, який означає, що зусилля занадто перевищують зиск від них.

Хочу замінити більш українським висловом. Знайшов лише [це](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

> ∆ **Шко́да [й] за́ходу (пра́ці)** — нічого не вийде, не варто зусиль і т.
>   ін. "Бач, якої співа! — дума Хапко, — Лестками закида. Закидай,
>   закидай, тільки й шкода заходу! Не схитрувати!" (Вовчок, VI, 1956,
>   279); — Шкода, кажу, пане, й заходу! не задля нас, певно, роблена ця
>   мебель. Сідаймо де інде,— на софі, абощо! (Н.-Лев., І, 1956, 126); А
>   ви в ярмі падаєте Та якогось раю На тім світі благаєте? Немає! немає!
>   Шкода й праці (Шевч., І, 1963, 237);
>
> **Шко́да́ й га́дки** див. [га́дка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0);
>   **Шко́да́ й каза́ти (говори́ти)** — не варто й слів. — Ні, пане брате,
>   полягти од твоєї шаблі байдуже, а оддати бранку — ой-ой-ой!.. Шкода й
>   казати! Годі дармо балакати! (П. Куліш, Вибр., 1969, 105); — Устрель,
>   Тимоше! устрель, мій любий! — благає [жінка], стискаючи його за руку.—
>   Не буду стріляти, шкода й говорити (Вовчок, І, 1955, 55).

Не подобається їх прямолінійність.

Comment: Не зовсім те, але близько: *Багато галасу даремно*. *Діла на копійку, а балачок на карбованець.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- працювали

  - [за спасибі](http://sum.in.ua/s/spasybi)
  - [задурно](http://sum.in.ua/s/zadurno)
  - [марно](http://sum.in.ua/s/marno)
- наша робота

  - [пуста](http://sum.in.ua/s/pustyj)
  - [даремна](http://sum.in.ua/s/daremnyj)
  - [дурна](http://sum.in.ua/s/durnyj)
  - [ламаного гроша](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghrish) не варта
- не [варта була шкурка вичинки](http://sum.in.ua/s/vartyj)
- не варта була справа [заходу](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakhid)
- рік працювали, а вийшлов [пшик](http://sum.in.ua/s/pshyk)
- рік [товкли воду в ступі](http://sum.in.ua/s/voda)
- займалися [Сізіфовою працею](http://sum.in.ua/s/sizifiv)
- Мавпяча робота — калька з чи рос. "Мартышкин труд" чи віддалено з англ. "Monkey business"

Comment: + Не вартує виїденого яйця

Answer (score 2):

Близьке про непотрібну роботу - *Дурного робота*